# Prims algorithm : Graph Theory

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

Below is my Code for Prims algorithm, I am writing my own linked list as i have been asked to. It works fine for smaller number of vertices , but when vertices are large it fails.( I get 812800 as the answer for all large numbers as vertices).

Input Format:

First line has two integers , denoting the number of nodes in the graph and , denoting the number of edges in the graph.

The next  lines each consist of three space separated integers   , where  and  denote the two nodes between which the undirected edge exists,  denotes the length of edge between the corresponding nodes.

The last line has an integer , denoting the starting node.

If there are edges between the same pair of nodes with different weights, they are to be considered as is, like multiple edges.

Output Format:

Print a single integer denoting the total weight of tree so obtained (sum of weight of edges).

Sample Input 0

```
5 6
1 2 3
1 3 4
4 2 6
5 2 2
2 3 5
3 5 7
1
```

Sample Output 0

15

My code passes the above test case , but fails the below one( I get 812800 for all large numbers).

```
1000 1000
1 2 100
2 3 200
3 4 300
4 5 400
5 6 500
6 7 600
7 8 700
8 9 800
9 10 900
10 11 1000
11 12 1100
12 13 1200
13 14 1300
14 15 1400
15 16 1500
16 17 1600
17 18 1700
18 19 1800
19 20 1900
20 21 2000
21 22 2100
22 23 2200
23 24 2300
24 25 2400
25 26 2500
26 27 2600
27 28 2700
28 29 2800
29 30 2900
30 31 3000
31 32 3100
32 33 3200
33 34 3300
34 35 3400
35 36 3500
36 37 3600
37 38 3700
38 39 3800
39 40 3900
40 41 4000
41 42 4100
42 43 4200
43 44 4300
44 45 4400
45 46 4500
46 47 4600
47 48 4700
48 49 4800
49 50 4900
50 51 5000
51 52 5100
52 53 5200
53 54 5300
54 55 5400
55 56 5500
56 57 5600
57 58 5700
58 59 5800
59 60 5900
60 61 6000
61 62 6100
62 63 6200
63 64 6300
64 65 6400
65 66 6500
66 67 6600
67 68 6700
68 69 6800
69 70 6900
70 71 7000
71 72 7100
72 73 7200
73 74 7300
74 75 7400
75 76 7500
76 77 7600
77 78 7700
78 79 7800
79 80 7900
80 81 8000
81 82 8100
82 83 8200
83 84 8300
84 85 8400
85 86 8500
86 87 8600
87 88 8700
88 89 8800
89 90 8900
90 91 9000
91 92 9100
92 93 9200
93 94 9300
94 95 9400
95 96 9500
96 97 9600
97 98 9700
98 99 9800
99 100 9900
100 101 10000
101 102 10100
102 103 10200
103 104 10300
104 105 10400
105 106 10500
106 107 10600
107 108 10700
108 109 10800
109 110 10900
110 111 11000
111 112 11100
112 113 11200
113 114 11300
114 115 11400
115 116 11500
116 117 11600
117 118 11700
118 119 11800
119 120 11900
120 121 12000
121 122 12100
122 123 12200
123 124 12300
124 125 12400
125 126 12500
126 127 12600
127 128 12700
128 129 12800
129 130 12900
130 131 13000
131 132 13100
132 133 13200
133 134 13300
134 135 13400
135 136 13500
136 137 13600
137 138 13700
138 139 13800
139 140 13900
140 141 14000
141 142 14100
142 143 14200
143 144 14300
144 145 14400
145 146 14500
146 147 14600
147 148 14700
148 149 14800
149 150 14900
150 151 15000
151 152 15100
152 153 15200
153 154 15300
154 155 15400
155 156 15500
156 157 15600
157 158 15700
158 159 15800
159 160 15900
160 161 16000
161 162 16100
162 163 16200
163 164 16300
164 165 16400
165 166 16500
166 167 16600
167 168 16700
168 169 16800
169 170 16900
170 171 17000
171 172 17100
172 173 17200
173 174 17300
174 175 17400
175 176 17500
176 177 17600
177 178 17700
178 179 17800
179 180 17900
180 181 18000
181 182 18100
182 183 18200
183 184 18300
184 185 18400
185 186 18500
186 187 18600
187 188 18700
188 189 18800
189 190 18900
190 191 19000
191 192 19100
192 193 19200
193 194 19300
194 195 19400
195 196 19500
196 197 19600
197 198 19700
198 199 19800
199 200 19900
200 201 20000
201 202 20100
202 203 20200
203 204 20300
204 205 20400
205 206 20500
206 207 20600
207 208 20700
208 209 20800
209 210 20900
210 211 21000
211 212 21100
212 213 21200
213 214 21300
214 215 21400
215 216 21500
216 217 21600
217 218 21700
218 219 21800
219 220 21900
220 221 22000
221 222 22100
222 223 22200
223 224 22300
224 225 22400
225 226 22500
226 227 22600
227 228 22700
228 229 22800
229 230 22900
230 231 23000
231 232 23100
232 233 23200
233 234 23300
234 235 23400
235 236 23500
236 237 23600
237 238 23700
238 239 23800
239 240 23900
240 241 24000
241 242 24100
242 243 24200
243 244 24300
244 245 24400
245 246 24500
246 247 24600
247 248 24700
248 249 24800
249 250 24900
250 251 25000
251 252 25100
252 253 25200
253 254 25300
254 255 25400
255 256 25500
256 257 25600
257 258 25700
258 259 25800
259 260 25900
260 261 26000
261 262 26100
262 263 26200
263 264 26300
264 265 26400
265 266 26500
266 267 26600
267 268 26700
268 269 26800
269 270 26900
270 271 27000
271 272 27100
272 273 27200
273 274 27300
274 275 27400
275 276 27500
276 277 27600
277 278 27700
278 279 27800
279 280 27900
280 281 28000
281 282 28100
282 283 28200
283 284 28300
284 285 28400
285 286 28500
286 287 28600
287 288 28700
288 289 28800
289 290 28900
290 291 29000
291 292 29100
292 293 29200
293 294 29300
294 295 29400
295 296 29500
296 297 29600
297 298 29700
298 299 29800
299 300 29900
300 301 30000
301 302 30100
302 303 30200
303 304 30300
304 305 30400
305 306 30500
306 307 30600
307 308 30700
308 309 30800
309 310 30900
310 311 31000
311 312 31100
312 313 31200
313 314 31300
314 315 31400
315 316 31500
316 317 31600
317 318 31700
318 319 31800
319 320 31900
320 321 32000
321 322 32100
322 323 32200
323 324 32300
324 325 32400
325 326 32500
326 327 32600
327 328 32700
328 329 32800
329 330 32900
330 331 33000
331 332 33100
332 333 33200
333 334 33300
334 335 33400
335 336 33500
336 337 33600
337 338 33700
338 339 33800
339 340 33900
340 341 34000
341 342 34100
342 343 34200
343 344 34300
344 345 34400
345 346 34500
346 347 34600
347 348 34700
348 349 34800
349 350 34900
350 351 35000
351 352 35100
352 353 35200
353 354 35300
354 355 35400
355 356 35500
356 357 35600
357 358 35700
358 359 35800
359 360 35900
360 361 36000
361 362 36100
362 363 36200
363 364 36300
364 365 36400
365 366 36500
366 367 36600
367 368 36700
368 369 36800
369 370 36900
370 371 37000
371 372 37100
372 373 37200
373 374 37300
374 375 37400
375 376 37500
376 377 37600
377 378 37700
378 379 37800
379 380 37900
380 381 38000
381 382 38100
382 383 38200
383 384 38300
384 385 38400
385 386 38500
386 387 38600
387 388 38700
388 389 38800
389 390 38900
390 391 39000
391 392 39100
392 393 39200
393 394 39300
394 395 39400
395 396 39500
396 397 39600
397 398 39700
398 399 39800
399 400 39900
400 401 40000
401 402 40100
402 403 40200
403 404 40300
404 405 40400
405 406 40500
406 407 40600
407 408 40700
408 409 40800
409 410 40900
410 411 41000
411 412 41100
412 413 41200
413 414 41300
414 415 41400
415 416 41500
416 417 41600
417 418 41700
418 419 41800
419 420 41900
420 421 42000
421 422 42100
422 423 42200
423 424 42300
424 425 42400
425 426 42500
426 427 42600
427 428 42700
428 429 42800
429 430 42900
430 431 43000
431 432 43100
432 433 43200
433 434 43300
434 435 43400
435 436 43500
436 437 43600
437 438 43700
438 439 43800
439 440 43900
440 441 44000
441 442 44100
442 443 44200
443 444 44300
444 445 44400
445 446 44500
446 447 44600
447 448 44700
448 449 44800
449 450 44900
450 451 45000
451 452 45100
452 453 45200
453 454 45300
454 455 45400
455 456 45500
456 457 45600
457 458 45700
458 459 45800
459 460 45900
460 461 46000
461 462 46100
462 463 46200
463 464 46300
464 465 46400
465 466 46500
466 467 46600
467 468 46700
468 469 46800
469 470 46900
470 471 47000
471 472 47100
472 473 47200
473 474 47300
474 475 47400
475 476 47500
476 477 47600
477 478 47700
478 479 47800
479 480 47900
480 481 48000
481 482 48100
482 483 48200
483 484 48300
484 485 48400
485 486 48500
486 487 48600
487 488 48700
488 489 48800
489 490 48900
490 491 49000
491 492 49100
492 493 49200
493 494 49300
494 495 49400
495 496 49500
496 497 49600
497 498 49700
498 499 49800
499 500 49900
500 501 50000
501 502 50100
502 503 50200
503 504 50300
504 505 50400
505 506 50500
506 507 50600
507 508 50700
508 509 50800
509 510 50900
510 511 51000
511 512 51100
512 513 51200
513 514 51300
514 515 51400
515 516 51500
516 517 51600
517 518 51700
518 519 51800
519 520 51900
520 521 52000
521 522 52100
522 523 52200
523 524 52300
524 525 52400
525 526 52500
526 527 52600
527 528 52700
528 529 52800
529 530 52900
530 531 53000
531 532 53100
532 533 53200
533 534 53300
534 535 53400
535 536 53500
536 537 53600
537 538 53700
538 539 53800
539 540 53900
540 541 54000
541 542 54100
542 543 54200
543 544 54300
544 545 54400
545 546 54500
546 547 54600
547 548 54700
548 549 54800
549 550 54900
550 551 55000
551 552 55100
552 553 55200
553 554 55300
554 555 55400
555 556 55500
556 557 55600
557 558 55700
558 559 55800
559 560 55900
560 561 56000
561 562 56100
562 563 56200
563 564 56300
564 565 56400
565 566 56500
566 567 56600
567 568 56700
568 569 56800
569 570 56900
570 571 57000
571 572 57100
572 573 57200
573 574 57300
574 575 57400
575 576 57500
576 577 57600
577 578 57700
578 579 57800
579 580 57900
580 581 58000
581 582 58100
582 583 58200
583 584 58300
584 585 58400
585 586 58500
586 587 58600
587 588 58700
588 589 58800
589 590 58900
590 591 59000
591 592 59100
592 593 59200
593 594 59300
594 595 59400
595 596 59500
596 597 59600
597 598 59700
598 599 59800
599 600 59900
600 601 60000
601 602 60100
602 603 60200
603 604 60300
604 605 60400
605 606 60500
606 607 60600
607 608 60700
608 609 60800
609 610 60900
610 611 61000
611 612 61100
612 613 61200
613 614 61300
614 615 61400
615 616 61500
616 617 61600
617 618 61700
618 619 61800
619 620 61900
620 621 62000
621 622 62100
622 623 62200
623 624 62300
624 625 62400
625 626 62500
626 627 62600
627 628 62700
628 629 62800
629 630 62900
630 631 63000
631 632 63100
632 633 63200
633 634 63300
634 635 63400
635 636 63500
636 637 63600
637 638 63700
638 639 63800
639 640 63900
640 641 64000
641 642 64100
642 643 64200
643 644 64300
644 645 64400
645 646 64500
646 647 64600
647 648 64700
648 649 64800
649 650 64900
650 651 65000
651 652 65100
652 653 65200
653 654 65300
654 655 65400
655 656 65500
656 657 65600
657 658 65700
658 659 65800
659 660 65900
660 661 66000
661 662 66100
662 663 66200
663 664 66300
664 665 66400
665 666 66500
666 667 66600
667 668 66700
668 669 66800
669 670 66900
670 671 67000
671 672 67100
672 673 67200
673 674 67300
674 675 67400
675 676 67500
676 677 67600
677 678 67700
678 679 67800
679 680 67900
680 681 68000
681 682 68100
682 683 68200
683 684 68300
684 685 68400
685 686 68500
686 687 68600
687 688 68700
688 689 68800
689 690 68900
690 691 69000
691 692 69100
692 693 69200
693 694 69300
694 695 69400
695 696 69500
696 697 69600
697 698 69700
698 699 69800
699 700 69900
700 701 70000
701 702 70100
702 703 70200
703 704 70300
704 705 70400
705 706 70500
706 707 70600
707 708 70700
708 709 70800
709 710 70900
710 711 71000
711 712 71100
712 713 71200
713 714 71300
714 715 71400
715 716 71500
716 717 71600
717 718 71700
718 719 71800
719 720 71900
720 721 72000
721 722 72100
722 723 72200
723 724 72300
724 725 72400
725 726 72500
726 727 72600
727 728 72700
728 729 72800
729 730 72900
730 731 73000
731 732 73100
732 733 73200
733 734 73300
734 735 73400
735 736 73500
736 737 73600
737 738 73700
738 739 73800
739 740 73900
740 741 74000
741 742 74100
742 743 74200
743 744 74300
744 745 74400
745 746 74500
746 747 74600
747 748 74700
748 749 74800
749 750 74900
750 751 75000
751 752 75100
752 753 75200
753 754 75300
754 755 75400
755 756 75500
756 757 75600
757 758 75700
758 759 75800
759 760 75900
760 761 76000
761 762 76100
762 763 76200
763 764 76300
764 765 76400
765 766 76500
766 767 76600
767 768 76700
768 769 76800
769 770 76900
770 771 77000
771 772 77100
772 773 77200
773 774 77300
774 775 77400
775 776 77500
776 777 77600
777 778 77700
778 779 77800
779 780 77900
780 781 78000
781 782 78100
782 783 78200
783 784 78300
784 785 78400
785 786 78500
786 787 78600
787 788 78700
788 789 78800
789 790 78900
790 791 79000
791 792 79100
792 793 79200
793 794 79300
794 795 79400
795 796 79500
796 797 79600
797 798 79700
798 799 79800
799 800 79900
800 801 80000
801 802 80100
802 803 80200
803 804 80300
804 805 80400
805 806 80500
806 807 80600
807 808 80700
808 809 80800
809 810 80900
810 811 81000
811 812 81100
812 813 81200
813 814 81300
814 815 81400
815 816 81500
816 817 81600
817 818 81700
818 819 81800
819 820 81900
820 821 82000
821 822 82100
822 823 82200
823 824 82300
824 825 82400
825 826 82500
826 827 82600
827 828 82700
828 829 82800
829 830 82900
830 831 83000
831 832 83100
832 833 83200
833 834 83300
834 835 83400
835 836 83500
836 837 83600
837 838 83700
838 839 83800
839 840 83900
840 841 84000
841 842 84100
842 843 84200
843 844 84300
844 845 84400
845 846 84500
846 847 84600
847 848 84700
848 849 84800
849 850 84900
850 851 85000
851 852 85100
852 853 85200
853 854 85300
854 855 85400
855 856 85500
856 857 85600
857 858 85700
858 859 85800
859 860 85900
860 861 86000
861 862 86100
862 863 86200
863 864 86300
864 865 86400
865 866 86500
866 867 86600
867 868 86700
868 869 86800
869 870 86900
870 871 87000
871 872 87100
872 873 87200
873 874 87300
874 875 87400
875 876 87500
876 877 87600
877 878 87700
878 879 87800
879 880 87900
880 881 88000
881 882 88100
882 883 88200
883 884 88300
884 885 88400
885 886 88500
886 887 88600
887 888 88700
888 889 88800
889 890 88900
890 891 89000
891 892 89100
892 893 89200
893 894 89300
894 895 89400
895 896 89500
896 897 89600
897 898 89700
898 899 89800
899 900 89900
900 901 90000
901 902 90100
902 903 90200
903 904 90300
904 905 90400
905 906 90500
906 907 90600
907 908 90700
908 909 90800
909 910 90900
910 911 91000
911 912 91100
912 913 91200
913 914 91300
914 915 91400
915 916 91500
916 917 91600
917 918 91700
918 919 91800
919 920 91900
920 921 92000
921 922 92100
922 923 92200
923 924 92300
924 925 92400
925 926 92500
926 927 92600
927 928 92700
928 929 92800
929 930 92900
930 931 93000
931 932 93100
932 933 93200
933 934 93300
934 935 93400
935 936 93500
936 937 93600
937 938 93700
938 939 93800
939 940 93900
940 941 94000
941 942 94100
942 943 94200
943 944 94300
944 945 94400
945 946 94500
946 947 94600
947 948 94700
948 949 94800
949 950 94900
950 951 95000
951 952 95100
952 953 95200
953 954 95300
954 955 95400
955 956 95500
956 957 95600
957 958 95700
958 959 95800
959 960 95900
960 961 96000
961 962 96100
962 963 96200
963 964 96300
964 965 96400
965 966 96500
966 967 96600
967 968 96700
968 969 96800
969 970 96900
970 971 97000
971 972 97100
972 973 97200
973 974 97300
974 975 97400
975 976 97500
976 977 97600
977 978 97700
978 979 97800
979 980 97900
980 981 98000
981 982 98100
982 983 98200
983 984 98300
984 985 98400
985 986 98500
986 987 98600
987 988 98700
988 989 98800
989 990 98900
990 991 99000
991 992 99100
992 993 99200
993 994 99300
994 995 99400
995 996 99500
996 997 99600
997 998 99700
998 999 99800
999 1000 99900
1000 1 100000
337
```

Please tell me where I'm making a mistake.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prim {

    public static void main(String args[]) {


   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   int N = scanner.nextInt();
   int m = scanner.nextInt();

   Graph g = new Graph(N);

   for(int i=0;i<m;i++) {

       int u =scanner.nextInt() -1;
       int v =scanner.nextInt() -1;
       int w =scanner.nextInt();


      g.addEdge(u,v,w);   
    }
   int s = scanner.nextInt()-1;

   g.prim(s);
}


static class Graph{

 int V;
 static LinkedList adjacencyList[];
 static int key[] ;
 static LinkedList L;
 static Integer parent[];

  Graph(int v){
        V = v;
        adjacencyList = new LinkedList[v];
        key = new int[v];
        parent = new Integer[v];
        L = new LinkedList();

        for(int i=0;i<v;i++) {
            adjacencyList[i] = new LinkedList();
            key[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            parent[i] = null;
            L.add(i);
        }

    }

    void addEdge(int u,int v, int w) {
        adjacencyList[u].add(v,w);
        adjacencyList[v].add(u,w);
    }

    long ans =0;
     void prim(int s) {

        key[s] = 0;
        while(L.head!=null){
        int u = getNodeMinkey();
        L.remove(u);

        if(parent[u] != null){
            Node n = adjacencyList[u].head;
            while(n!=null){
                if( n.data == parent[u]){
                    ans+=n.weight;
                }
                n = n.next;
            }
        }

        Node n = adjacencyList[u].head;

        while(n!=null){
            int i = n.data;
            int w = n.weight;
            if(key[i] > w){
                key[i] = w;
                parent[i] = u;
            }
            n = n.next;
         }
        }

        System.out.print(ans);
        //return A; 
    }


    static int getNodeMinkey(){
        Node n = L.head;
        int i = n.data; 
        int minkey = key[i];

        n= n.next;

        while(n != null) {
        if(minkey > key[n.data] ){
            minkey =key[n.data];
            i = n.data;
        }
        n= n.next;
        }

        return i;
    }

}

static class LinkedList{
    Node head;

    void add(int d,int w) {

        if(head == null){
            head = new Node(d,w);
            return;
        }

        Node n = head;
        while(n!=null){
            if(n.next == null){
                n.next = new Node(d,w);
                return;
            }
            n= n.next;
        }

    }

    void add(int d) {

        if(head == null){
            head = new Node(d);
            return;
        }

        Node n = head;
        while(n!=null){
            if(n.next == null){
                n.next = new Node(d);
                return;
            }
            n= n.next;
        }

    }

    void remove(int a){

        if (head == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(head.data == a){
            head = head.next;
            return;
        }

        Node n = head;
        while(n.next != null) {
            if( n.next.data == a ) {
              n.next = n.next.next; 
              return;
            }
            n= n.next;
        }

    }

}

static class Node{

    Integer data;
    Integer weight;
    Node next;

    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        weight =0;
    }

    Node(int d,int w){
        data = d;
        weight = w;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I used values /100 to avoid usage of big numbers. Your code starts to sum edges at 127, and loops until it reaches 0. In fact, 128*127/2 (sum of numbers between 1 and 127) is exactly 8128.
I think that your adjacencyList still keeps references to nodes that you (think to!) remove: you DO NOT remove them, since you simply assign n.next=n.next.next, so reference remains.

Update LinkedList.remove() code in this way:

```
    void remove(int a) {
        ...
        Node n = head;
        while (n.next != null) {
            if (n.next.data == a) {
                Node z = n.next; // add this
                n.next = n.next.next;
                z.next=null;  // add this
                z.data=0; // add this
                return;
        ...
```

and your answer is 499500, that seems to me the correct one.